# How do I read in integer and convert it to ASCII character and?

Tags: c++, int, ascii

I'm new to this C++ environment and might need a simple help.

Let's say you have an array

```
const char digits[] = "01234567..XYZ"
```

How do you convert integer using ASCII conversion by reading in an integer (ex. 123) and display it on the console separately like 1, 2, and 3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to program C++, then you should use `std::cout` instead of `stdout`, and `std::ostream` instead of `FILE`.

Comment: As for your problem (and I assume it's a school or other learning assignment), think about how decimal numbers are built up, and what happens if you e.g. divide `123` with `10`. Then learn about the modulo operator `%`.

Comment: Do you want to ouptut "123" or the base36 value of `123`?

Comment: @SimonKraemer I just want the output 123. I just want to convert 1,2, and 3 separately and print it separately as well

Answer (score 2):

You can create a loop and then simply do it like this:

```
c = (char)(i%10);  //To extract the last digit of an integer

i = i/10;  //To remove the last decimal digit from an integer

char c = '0' + i; //To convert a binary digit stored in a char to an ASCII digit
```

Comment: That doesn't meet the stated requirement of no headers or includes

Comment: @Peter:- Updated my answer!

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
#include <cstdio>

//void decout(unsigned int number, FILE * stream)
//{
//  fprintf(stream, "%u", number);
//}

void decout(unsigned int number, FILE * stream)
{
    unsigned int tmp = number;
    unsigned int div = 1;
    while ((tmp/=10) > 0) { div *= 10; }
    while (div > 0) { fputc(((number/div)%10) + '0', stream); div /= 10; }
}

void decout_alt(unsigned int number, FILE * stream)
{
    bool printZero = 0;
    for (unsigned int max = 1000000000, p = (number / max) % 10; max > 0; max /= 10, p = max>0?(number / max) % 10:0) //32-bit only
    {
        if (p != 0 || printZero) {
            fputc(p + '0', stream); printZero = true;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *const* argv)
{
    decout(123, stdout);
    decout_alt(123, stdout);
}
```

Comment: This works but is there other way of doing it by using fputc?